# OpenSUSE - installing libqt4-devel

Tags: opensuse

I've got a minimal no-gui installation of OpenSuse 11.4 (x64).  I'm trying to build CutyCapt which requires libqt4-devel.  When I try to install it with the Yast, I get the following:

```
libqt4-develop-4.7.1-7.1.x86_64 requires Mesa-devel, but this requirement cannot be provided
```

Possible solutions:

```
deinstallation of patterns-openSUSE-minimal_base-11.4-6.9.1.x86-64
+ others
```

My questions are:

1. What does all this mean?  What is Mesa-devel and what is patterns-minimal_base?
2. Will something break if I go ahead and de-install the minimal base pattern?

Comment: `rpm -qi patterns-openSUSE-minimal_base` will show the description of the package.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSUSE's patterns are like little package bundles and configurations which make it easy for you to run/install/update stuff. Look [here](http://lizards.opensuse.org/2009/10/07/about-patterns-versus-packages/) for a quick history of patterns and why they came to be.

Removing the pattern `patterns-openSUSE-minimal_base-11.4-6.9.1.x86-64` probably won't do anything you would allow you to install your qt4 library. These things happen sometimes with patterns, that's why I try and build my system from individual packages.